# Weird crash when calling closure with generic parameters in Swift 3

Tags: swift, generics, crash, closures

here I have a Protocol:

```
protocol CrashProtocol {
    associatedtype T

    static func tryCrash(_ dummyInt: Int,
                         with closure: ((T) -> Void))
}
```

A Base class that implements it:

```
class Crash<M>: CrashProtocol {
    typealias T = M

    class func tryCrash(_ dummyInt: Int,
                        with closure: ((M) -> Void)) {
        print("Crash tryCrash")
    }
}
```

And a derived class inherit the base class:

```
class DerivedCrash: Crash<DummyObject> {

    override class func tryCrash(_ dummyInt: Int, with closure: ((DummyObject) -> Void)) {
        super.tryCrash(dummyInt, with: closure)

        print("Derived tryCrash")
        let obj = DummyObject.init()
        closure(obj)
    }
}
```

Now whenever I try

```
DerivedCrash.tryCrash(1) { _ in
            print("Never reach here")
}
```

I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" crash. You can find my testing code [here](https://github.com/NSFish/SwiftClosureCrash).
I've done my share of debugging, but only find out that the memory address causing the crash points to a Swift.Int instance, which I do not use..
And if I change the calling code a little bit, the code would crash after the closure being executed..

```
DerivedCrash.tryCrash(1) { (obj: DummyObject) in
    //print("Never reach here")
    print("print as expected and then crash")
}
```

If anyone could shred in some light, I would be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `NSObject` to `associatedtype` and now it doesn't crash.
It **doesn't answer** your question, but maybe this temp solution will help you

```
protocol CrashProtocol {
    associatedtype T: NSObject

    static func tryCrash(_ dummyInt: Int,
                         with closure: ((T) -> Void))
}

class Crash<M:NSObject>: CrashProtocol {
    typealias T = M

    class func tryCrash(_ dummyInt: Int,
                        with closure: ((M) -> Void)) {
        print("Crash tryCrash")
    }
}
```

Comment: use DummyObject rather than NSObject as your associated type, since NSObject is too generic.

Comment: Thanks @WheelBuy you made my day ! 
I still could not figure out why this crash happens, but at least I can keep coding with your help..